# How can I remove a modulo out of my math operation?

Tags: java, modulo

My prof does not like the use of modulo since it's not efficient enough, but I'm not sure how else I can get the same answer using a logic operator or something. Can someone help me out with how I can do this?

```
j = (j + 1) % a.length;
```

Comment: *sighs* at professor

Comment: You can do this with a conditional (assuming `j` is already `< length`).  But that probably isn't faster.

Comment: I agree. The professor's concerns are not well-founded. Except for a specialized application, a modulo is generally faster than a conditional jump in many languages, and even if it were slower, this microoptimization is still orders of magnitude slower than disk access or network latencies.

Comment: Switch schools. Or drop the class and take it when there's a new prof. Modulo can provide some of the most elegant, efficient, and readable code.

Comment: It's fascinating how quickly a three word comment can skyrocket in up-votes like that.

Comment: @Cruncher Or talk to the professor and reference discussions here and other evidence.

Comment: @Izmaki The fact that it's 3 words.

Comment: @Cruncher: that might be a slight exageration. Pointing the prof to this question would be a better start

Comment: I suggest that if the prof tells you "black is white" you answer that, take your grade and go.

Comment: Are there any assumptions about j and a.length? Otherwise I very much doubt anyone will find faster code. Because if there was; java would do it

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
 int k = a.length;
 int d = (j+1)/k;
 j = (j+1) - d*k
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is that on most systems, / and % should be the same operation anyway, just storing a different part of the result, so it doesn't actually change the speed at all.

Comment: So, if the prof hates one modulo, he or she will really hate one division plus one multiplication.

Comment: Presumably this will be slower than % then? Not that it matters, its all ridiculous micro optimisation

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can see of doing this without a modulo is still not great:

```
j = (++j < a.length)? j : (j - a.length);
```

Alternately, for more readability:

```
j++;
j = (j < a.length)? j : (j - a.length);
```

or

```
j++;
if (j >= a.length) {
    j -= a.length;
}
```

Also, I'm not entirely sure about how Java does with loop prediction, but at least in C, the following would be slightly better for speed, if less readable, since the general assumption is that the argument to the if statement will be true, and `j < a.length` more often than not (Unless `a.length <= 2`, which seems unlikely.)

```
j++;
if(j < a.length) {
}
else {
    j -= a.length;
}
```

If the initial value of `j` is outside the range `0` to `a.length` (inclusive-exclusive), then the only solutions either use a modulus or division, which, being the same operation, are the same speed, or a loop of subtraction, which will essentially accomplish the same thing as modulus on a very old processor, which is slower than the built in operation for modulus on any current processor I know about.

Comment: Sorry, trying to read a statement where you use a pre-increment to a variable you're both assigning to and using elsewhere in the same statement gives me a headache.  Even if it works.  No points for cramming everything into one line unless you're programming in APL.  :)

Comment: @ajb I can take the blame on that one, was my idea. Seemed like a good idea at the time, but I see your point.

Comment: I fear I may be missing something, but what if j is huge, like 1000000? and a.length is small, like 5

Comment: How big `j` is doesn't really matter, only how it compares to `a.length`. This (as with most of the other solutions) assumes that `j` is always kept between `0` and `a.length` (inclusive-exclusive), since there's no way to do it without either using a divmod operation or implementing such an operation with - (even more inefficiently) otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
j = j + 1;
if (j >= a.length) {
    j = j - a.length; // assumes j was less than length before increment
}
```

@ajp suggests another solution that actually would work ok.

```
j = j + 1;
if (j >= a.length) { // assumes j was less than length before increment
    j = 0; 
}
```

If I was writing the code, id write it this way, just in case. It has very little additional overhead and removes the "assumes"

```
j = j + 1;
while (j >= a.length) {
    j = j - a.length;
}
```

Of course, the `%` would be a good way to do it too. Unless one is your professor.

This could be faster or slower than a divide/modulo depending on the cost of a jump (and any effect that has on the instruction pipeline/lookahead) and the efficiency of the integer division instructions.

Old processors would likely do better with the jump. More modern ones with the divide.

Comment: I suggest running some benchmarks when you have time, to strengthen your answer.

Comment: Note: if j was "less than" length before the increment, your conditional will always fail.  You may mean "assumes j was <= length", or you may mean `if (j >= a.length)`.

Comment: Also: if the assumption is correct, then you may as well say `if (j >= a.length) j = 0;`.  Sometimes that makes it clearer what's going on.

Comment: Unfortunately this is slower than modulo ): Benchmarked with 1mil elements. Thanks though :)

Comment: @user1730056 Depends on the machine and processor, I suspect. For all we know, OP is in some embedded programming class that's using ancient 8-bit processors.

Comment: @LeeMeador Like 6502's?  I used to write assembly language for those.  They didn't have divide instructions.

Comment: If this is slower than using modulo, you probably can't get any better than what you have, unless you're doing modulo by some specific number (Like a power of 2, for example.)

Comment: @LeeMeador considering that you should be compiling the same byte code for any machine, you need a JVM, not a compiler, that's what differs between platforms.

Comment: @Cruncher The Java compiler (javac) generates the byte code the same for any processor. The byte code is executed by the JVM. Some are probably more efficient than others. And some processors have JIT compilers that compile the byte code to native instructions if the code gets executed often enough. (Some don't) There may be exceptions but that's the general way it works.

Comment: @LeeMeador That's what I just said, but with more detail. My point was, the JVM is the necessary component for java to work on a platform, not the compiler. If need be you could compile the bytecode on a different machine.

Answer (score 1):

Think of what you are doing here. You are essentially saying:

```
if j + 1 is smaller than a.length, set j to j + 1
otherwise, we set j to a value smaller than a.length
```

This pseudocode should give you a very clear hint to the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "a value smaller than a.length"

Comment: @RichardTingle I think he means `a value that is a.length less than j` or some factor of a.length less than j, such that the value is less than a.length